# Данные отправляются в БД без нажатия на submit. Как это исправить?

Tags: php

Перехожу на страницу добавления материала и через секунду данные отправляются, пустые и без нажатия. Как это исправить?

Можно было бы запретить пустую отправку, но я этого не хочу. Хочу просто предотвратить повторную отправку данных.

Код:

```
<form action="send.php" method="post">
 <div id="title_field">
<input id="title" name="post_title" type="text" placeholder="Заголовок" />

<textarea id="text" name="post_text"></textarea>

<input id="tags" name="post_tags" type="text" placeholder="Теги"/>
 </div>

 <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Опубликовать" />

 </form>
```

---

```
 <?php
$db = mysql_connect("host","username","password");
mysql_select_db("a9119841_blog" ,$db);

mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO records(title, text, date) VALUES ('$_POST[post_title]', '$_POST[post_text]', NOW())", $db);

header('Location: 'index_page']);
exit();
 ?>
```

Comment: SQL-injection detected  

Приведенный код никак не заставляет браузер отправлять пустые данные формы.

Comment: отправка происходит. Вся база данных в пустых записях

Comment: Уточните, приведенный php код у вас в каком файле? send.php? А сама разметка формы где и как выводится? Возможно вы при каждом обращении к форме выполняете приведенный php код, и так как отсутствует какая-либо проверка на наличие POST данных, у вас на каждое обращение к странице отдельный вызов.

Answer (score 1):

Хорошо бы проверять на наличие данных в пост запросе:

```
if(isset($_POST))
{
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO records(title, text, date) VALUES 
    ('$_POST[post_title]', '$_POST[post_text]', NOW())", $db);
    //...
}
```